# Buttons and get requests

Tags: javascript, html

I am fairly new to coding and I am trying to make a button in html that when pushed the data from a get request in JavaScript shows up. When I do the request itself and console.log it, the info shows in the console, but for some reason I can not get it when I click a button.

Comment: Please use JsFiddle, JsBin or Codesandbox.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. So glad you are here. Could you please look through [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on how to add code to your question, or [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) on how to format helpful questions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, maybe it will clarify you this problem a little: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nn1wym

Answer (score 0):

use preventDefault in the onclick function.
like:
`<button onclick="fun(this)">Click</button>
<script>
function fun(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
</script>`